# Need help with Perl regex commenting out lines in html

Tags: regular-expression, perl, html

I am trying to comment out a line item entry in a bunch of html documents.

I need to match a pattern that has a few variations and the substitution will the be matched pattern surrounded by `<!--  -->`

The variations are as follows:

```html
<li><a href="latest-news.htm" >Latest News</a></li>

<li><a href="pages/latest-news.htm" >Latest News</a></li>

<li><a href="../../latest-news.htm"  >Latest News</a>
      </li>
```

Those are the main variations but there can also be some where latest-news.php instead of .htm.
Another variation is only one set of ../

I have this so far:

```bsh
     find ./ -name "*.htm" -exec perl -p0e 's/(^\s*<li><a href="((\.\.\/)*|pages\/)?latest-news\.(htm|php)"\s*>Latest News<\/a>\s*(\n)?\s*<\/li>\s*)/<!-- $1 -->/g' {} \; | grep -C 1 "latest-news" | grep -C 1 "latest-news"
```

I don't know what's going wrong there but I'm not matching anything.
The grep at the end should show me each instance of this line in each file found and they are not getting commented out.

I'm just starting to use perl and regex and this is one of the most complex attempts I've made so far.

Is what I'm trying to do possible or is there a better way to accomplish this?

I've tried using some regex testing sites but most do not have a standard perl regex test and the ones using PHP regex and match all the variations do not work when I try to run it.

Please let me know if I can add any more information.

I was able to get some of the multi line variations matched a couple of weeks ago but I cannot figure out which version of my command did that. I am currently starting over from a backup of all the files so I can test more.

### my versions

```bsh
$> perl -v

This is perl 5, version 28, subversion 1 (v5.28.1) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
(with 61 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)

$> grep -V
grep (GNU grep) 3.3

$> uname -mrs
Linux 5.3.0-24-generic x86_64

$> lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.10
Release:    19.10
Codename:   eoan
```

**UPDATE**

I updated my regex search to:

```bsh
(<li><a href="(\.\.\/|pages\/)*latest-news.(htm|php)"\s*>Latest News<\/a>\s*(\n)?\s*<\/li>)\n?
```

This caught all but a few of the single line variations. Some were still not matched if they didn't have `../` or `page/` before `latest-news.htm`. 
There is an instance of a line that has more white space (3 tabs vs 1 tab or space characters) before the `<li>` that wasn't matched.

If I add `\s*` before the `<li>` in my search pattern the comment starts at the end of the previous line but still does not catch the line with more white space in the beginning.

```
            <li><a href="latest-news.htm" class="current">Latest News</a></li>
```

^ This is the line that still won't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
perl -0777 -pe '
   s{<li>\s*<a\s[^>]*href="[^"]*latest-news\.(?:htm|php)"[^>]*>\s*Latest News\s*</a>\s*</li>}
    {<!-- $& -->}g' your-file.htm
```

would be enough.

Note that if you don't enable the multi-line mode (with the `m` flag), `^` only matches at the start of the subject (each NUL-delimited record with `-0`, the whole input with `-0777`), not the start of *any line in the subject*. Also note that `\s` matches on newline as well. Use `\h` if you only want to match on horizontal spacing (but AFAIK HTML makes no difference between horizontal and vertical, NL and SPC are interchangeable as far as its syntax is concerned at least outside of things like `<pre>`, `CDATA...`, quoted attribute values..).

To avoid doing the substitution inside already commented sections, you could do:

```
perl -0777 -pe '
   s{(<!--.*?-->)|<li>\s*<a\s[^>]*href="[^"]*latest-news\.(?:htm|php)"[^>]*>\s*Latest News\s*</a>\s*</li>}
    {$1 // "<!-- $& -->"}gse' your-file.htm
```

Comment: I'll have to try that when I get home from work. What is the purpose of [^>], [^"] and [^>] in your example?

Comment: @monkadelicd `[^>]*` is a run of any number of characters other than `>`, so that's *allowing anything provided we stay within the `<...>` tag*

Comment: ah ok. Thank you. Can you elaborate on the -0777 option? I'm fairly inexperienced with Perl and am attempting to learn it more completely.

Comment: @monkadelicd, see the doc (`perldoc perlrun`). `-0<octal>` specifies the input record delimiter (instead of the default of "newline"). `-0` (which you use in your question) uses byte 0 as the delimiter. You'd use that to process NUL-delimited records like the output of `find -print0`. `777` is an impossible byte value. It's the canonical way to process the input as one record, the *slurp mode*.

Comment: Thank you so much! That did it. I'll have to do a closer analysis of the difference between your pattern and mine but I think I've picked up at least a couple of good pointers.

Comment: One more question. I've already got some of the lines commented out. This will double comment those. I tried adding ```^\s*``` to the beginning but that misses the lines I was missing before. How can I ignore lines that have ```<!--```. I tried adding ```[^<!--]``` and ```[^(<!--)]``` to the beginning of my pattern but that doesn't do it.

Comment: @monkadelicd, see edit. `[...]` only ever matches a single character. `[^<!--]` matches any character other than `<`, `!` to `-`. perl has look-behind and look-ahead operators but it doesn't support variable length look behinds like you would need here. In any case, that wouldn't help in cases like `<!-- text <li>...</li> more text -->`

Comment: Ok I think that's all I'll try to squeeze out of you. I need to make time to read the camel book. Thanks again!